# Conflicting dependencies (bcprov-jdk15on vs. bcprov-jdk16)

Tags: java, bouncycastle

How to resolve the issue with two different version of Bouncy Castle namely bcprov-jdk15on-1.52 and bcprov-jdk16-1.46 when I need both of them for different things? I need bcprov-jdk15on-1.52 to use Box java sdk and bcprov-jdk16-1.46 to run the SSHClient.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is impossible.

The only way around this is if you're able to split it up into 2 separate applications with each their own bcprov dependency, or updating the part that uses the version 15 to be able to use 16 instead ...

Comment: Thank-you for the reply. Currently I have shifted myself to avoid using ssh and instead I'm using Jsch library.